# How do I set a boolean value on a column that can be used in my MVC Web Application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

In my MVC web application I have a model class that talks to a SQL database view that is stored in my Azure SQL Database.  The model looks like this:

```
namespace GanttTest.Models
{
    [Table("GanttTest")]
    public class Task
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public int? Duration { get; set; }        
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OptionsEnd { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OptionsStart { get; set; }
        public bool Unscheduled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

At the top of the model a table is specified which is an SQL View that I created.

As this model serves a Gantt chart, I have a dto in place for the data:

```
namespace GanttTest.Models
{
    public class TaskDto
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string start_date { get; set; }
        public int? duration { get; set; }
        public decimal progress { get; set; }
        public int? parent { get; set; }
        public string options_start { get; set; }
        public string options_end { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public bool unscheduled { get; set;}
        public bool open
        {
            get { return true; }
            set { }
        }

        public static explicit operator TaskDto(Task task)
        {
            return new TaskDto
            {
                id = task.Id,
                text = task.Text,
                start_date = task.StartDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") ?? "",
                options_start = task.OptionsStart?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") ?? "", /*Allows toString to be used on nullable types*/
                options_end = task.OptionsEnd?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") ?? "",
                duration = task.Duration,
                unscheduled = task.Unscheduled
            };
        }

        public static explicit operator Task(TaskDto task)
        {
            return new Task
            {
                Id = task.id,
                Text = task.text,
                StartDate = DateTime.Parse(task.start_date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                OptionsStart = DateTime.Parse(task.start_date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                OptionsEnd = DateTime.Parse(task.start_date, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Duration = task.duration,
                Unscheduled = task.unscheduled
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The method to grab the data which uses WebAPI is as follows:

```
 public IEnumerable<TaskDto> Get()
 {
     var task = db.Tasks.ToList().Select(t => (TaskDto)t);
     return task;
 }
```

The view has a `CASE` defined for setting the conditional value of a column named `Unscheduled` which you can see in the model above.  It's a boolean and so can it's a true or false.

```
(CASE WHEN Onhire IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Unscheduled
```

The problem I have is that when I run my application and the data is gathered I get an error of:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Unscheduled' property on
>   'Task' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this
>   property to a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'. '

I have tried setting the value in many ways from the numbers you see above, to the words `true` and `false` but the error changes to each datatype I try and nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to define the boolean values that I am not using? I'm a bit confused.  Documentation on the subject shows the use of 0 and 1.

Comment: Maybe `DbType.Boolean`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DenisRubashkin I've managed to fix this by casting the column as a BIT.  I'll resolve and answer tomorrow once the time has passed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using objects from the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace the C# boolean datatype corresponds to the bit SQL Server data type.  For example, the following sets the "BitColumn" to 1.  For objects in the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace the `OleDbType.Boolean` data type can be used, with the C# boolean datatype still correlating to the SQL Server bit datatype.

```
    string cmdText = @"UPDATE DBO.TABLE SET BitColumn =  = @bVal";
    bool b = true;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);

        SqlParameter boolParameter = new SqlParameter("@bVal", SqlDbType.Bit);
        boolParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        boolParameter.Value = b;
        sql.Parameters.Add(boolParameter);

        conn.Open();

        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in this particular instance was to cast the column as a bit.  I found a different post on stack that highlighted SQL not passing data as a bit because it didn't know it was supposed to be one.  In this case, casting is a way of defining the type.

```
CAST(CASE WHEN fix1.Onhire IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS Unscheduled
```

The application the understands that it's a bit / boolean and not just a number/string or whatever else it tries to interperate it as .